# llvm 6.0 error with prefix header

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am developing simple app for iPhones. **Long time before I renamed it from tc01 to Time_Capsule_1.0**. After I updated Xcode to version 6, I started to get this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory:     '/Users/iosdevelpoeris/Desktop/Work/timecapsule-ios-app/tc01/tc01/tc01-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I checked my build settings, because that what most answers about this kind of error     suggested. The problem is that there everything looks fine.

In my project there is subfolder tc01 with prefix header file named Time_Capsule_1.0-Prefix.pch so **tc01/Time_Capsule_1.0-Prefix.pch** is written in column prefix header.

I found another answer suggesting to turn off option in LLVM 6.0 preprocessing, namely:
enable foundation assertions. This didn't help either.

Anybody has some idea what could cause the problem ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? . . . 
you could try is in your actual project change the name of the file to "c01-prefix.pch" then go into your build settings and and make sure your precompile prefix header value is the same . . .  let me know

Comment: Yes I solved it somehow. I cleared Xcode and as well I cloned fresh version of the project and it was soleved. I don't know which one of these two steps did it but finally I got it working. Just to note only clearing Xcode didn;t help when I did it for first time, not sure why ...